# Can one Activity use one of many Fragments with the same method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can one Activity use one of many Fragments with the same method?

I have a number of Fragments to accept a user's input for various information. Each Fragment is different and their use is determined by the tab selected by the user. I am currently using a switch statement to select the appropriate fragment to use in the Activity:

```
private static Fragment fragment;

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    boolean validTab = true;

    switch (tabSelected){
        case "Procedures":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new ProcedureRecordsFragment();
            Log.d(TAG, "fragment is: " + fragment);
            break;
        case "Prescriptions":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new PrescriptionRecordsFragment();
            Log.d(TAG, "fragment is: " + fragment);
            break;
        case "Immunizations":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new ImmunizationRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Medical Encounters":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new MedicalEncounterRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Allergies":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new AllergyRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Injuries":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new InjuryRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Obstetric History":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new ObstetricRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Family History":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new FamilyHistoryRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Social History":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new SocialHistoryRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Habits":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new HabitRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Development History":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new DevelopmentRecordsFragment();
            break;
        case "Demographics":
            Log.d(TAG, "To enter: " + tabSelected + "records");
            fragment = new DemographicRecordsFragment();
            break;*/
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Invalid tab reference");
            validTab = false;
            break;
        }
        if(validTab == true){
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }else if(validTab == false){
            Log.d(TAG, "Do nothing, invalid tab reference");
        }
```

This successfully displays the correct fragment as determined by the selected tab.

Each Fragment has the same method that returns user input, at the moment it is simply a String:

```
public String getUserInput(){
    return("String from the fragment!");
}
```

The Fragments' `getUserInout` method is intended to be accessed by the Activity's `saveRecord` method, added after success in displaying each Fragment:

```
public void saveRecord(MenuItem item){
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered: saveRecord");
    String s = fragment.getUserInput();
    Log.d(TAG, "String s says: " + s);
    Log.d(TAG, "fragment is: " + fragment);
}
```

The instruction `String s = fragment.getUserInput();` results in a Gradle build **"Cannot resolve method getUserInput"** error. When I comment out both `String s = fragment.getUserInput();` and `Log.d(TAG, "String s says: " + s);` and run the code, `Log.d(TAG, "fragment is: " + fragment)` displays the selected fragment's reference as generated by Gradle: such as **D/MedicalRecordActivity: fragment is: ProcedureRecordsFragment{6c827fa}** for the case instance and **D/MedicalRecordActivity: fragment is: ProcedureRecordsFragment{6c827fa #0 id=0x7f080084}** for the saveRecord method.

This indicates to me that Gradle produced code that creates one instance of the appropriate fragment as determined by the tab selection. I have found nothing in my research that provides me the information about an Activity using one of many Fragments that provides the Activity access to the active Fragment's methods. Can anyone point me to such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `interface`. This is essentially a contract that a class can claim to provide. So in your case, you have a contract for classes that provide user input. You could use something like:

```
interface UserInputProvider {
  public String getUserInput();
}
```

Your Fragment classes then just need to implement that interface, and mark that they override that method from the interface:

```
class MyFragment implements UserInputProvider {
  @Override
  public String getUserInput() {
    // your code to get input here
  }
}
```

Then you can just cast your Fragment to a UserInputProvider, if applicable:

```
public void saveRecord(MenuItem item) {
  if (fragment instanceof UserInputProvider) {
    String input = ((UserInputProvider) fragment).getUserInput();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I take it that I add the interface to the Activity and the Fragments then implement that interface. However, when I do that, AS tells me that it can't resolve UserInputProvider even though I have an import statement for the Activity. When I add the Activity's name to the "implements" statement, I get a 'cyclical inheritance...' warning. I am continuing to investigate your suggestion, because I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: You don't need your Activity to implement the interface, just the Fragments which actually provide that method. The root issue here is that the class `Fragment` doesn't have any method called `getUserInput()`, just your particular subclasses. So you need to cast to a particular type which has that method. You could either share a parent class, or use the interface in this case.

Comment: OK. My problem is that I'm self taught and just never understood interfaces. "Communicate with other fragments" in Developer puts the interface in the HeadlinesFragment, so I thought I was to put your suggested interface in the Activity. From reading [Communicate with other fragments](http://wiseassblog.com/tutorials/java/android/interface/2016/09/13/android-java-interfaces/), it is its own file. I'm working on your suggestion.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch! I actually learned something very useful in our interaction and I thank you for your time and effort. I now have an understanding of interfaces that makes sense.

Comment: Good to hear! I'm glad it helped you!